# HTTP2 defaulting to HTTP/1.1

Tags: java, http, netty, http2

I am trying to setup a apache load balancer to handle `HTTP2` connections, However the incoming connections default to `HTTP/1.1` 
The strange thing is this is happening only when the `HTTP2` connection originates from `netty HTTP2` library, when the request originates from `OKHTTP` library it goes through fine.

The SSLCipherSuite i am using

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM- 
SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128- 
SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256- 
SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
```

The Error seen with netty is

> io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:85)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.verifyFirstFrameIsSettings(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:350)

Comment: It is probably because the server is using SSL and netty is not (or vice versa). Is the server using SSL?

Comment: Yes both are over ssl, my other concern here is i am using self sign certificate. not sure if the netty codec_http2 library accepts self sign certificates

Comment: Hi ,is there solution around it , I am also facing a similar issue

Comment: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8717
The solution is the above link it was a apache config info.

Answer (score 0):

github.com/netty/netty/issues/8717 The solution is the above link it was a apache config info. `H2Direct on`